# Crear nodo y relación a partir de propiedad simple en lugar de objeto

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Neo4j, Spring Boot y Java. He creado diferentes clases:

- Paciente
- Clinica
- Documento

Una clínica puede tener varios pacientes, y los documentos se asocian a los pacientes. La relación entre paciente y clínica y documento la he creado sin problemas haciendo algo como esto:

```
public class Paciente {

    ...

    @GraphId
    private Long uid;

    @Relationship(type = "IN_CLINICA", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Clinica clinica;

    ...

    public void InClinica(Clinica clinica) {
        this.clinica = clinica;
    }

    ...
}
```

Y al insertar datos, en Neo4j la relación se ve así:

[image: Relación en Neo4j]

Ahora, esa relación entre nodos es de objeto a objeto. ¿Es posible crear una relación de nodo a nodo, en la que un nodo es un objeto y el otro es una propiedad simple? Por ejemplo, en la clase Documento hay una propiedad de tipo String llamada formato (que puede ser "PDF", "HTML", "XML", etc.). He intentado añadir un código similar al de Paciente/Clínica, pero no se crea un nodo "Formato" ni una relación Documento-Formato:

```
public class Documento {
    // Document info
    @GraphId private Long documentoId;
    public String Nombre;
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_FORMATO", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    public String formato;

    ...

    public void hasFormato(String formato) { this.formato = formato; }

    ...
}
```

¿Ser posible crear ese tipo de relaciones? Es decir, que se cree un nodo a partir de una propiedad y no de una clase. Y si sí, ¿cómo se haría? ¿O tendría que definir una clase Formato y entonces relacionar un objeto de esa clase con Documento? (cambiando los tipos de `public String formato` por algo como `public Formato formato`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactamente como dices al final: Un nodo siempre va a ser un objeto, nunca una propiedad suelta. La base de datos neo4j usa una semántica en la que los nodos representan objetos (siendo el label el "nombre de la clase", por hacer una analogía con POO) y las propiedades del nodo son los atributos de la clase.

En general se desaconseja hacer más tipos de objetos de los necesarios, por la rapidez de las búsquedas. Sin embargo, hay dos casos donde puede serte útil:

-Si en este caso el Formato va a tener más propiedades (tamaño o así), puede ser apropiado que esté aparte para tener sus propiedades relacionadas separadas del resto. En este caso también "es natural" tener una clase propia.

-Si vas a tener varios formatos distintos y quieres filtrar por ellos, puede serte útil tener un mismo nodo Formato al que estén unidos los diferentes Documentos. De esta forma la búsqueda no pasa por todos los Documentos sino que, empezando desde el nodo Formato, va más rápidamente sólo a los nodos Documento que están relacionados con ese nodo Formato.